# What are the link: Function "parameters" (scope, element, attrs)? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I've been using AngularJS for a couple months now and I've scoured the internet and my AngularJS Directives book for an answer to this.

In directives, I almost always see this block of code:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
    //body
}
```

What exactly are the items inside the function "scope, element, attrs"? This might be a stupid question but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to do google on it..here is one of the good link how it works http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/compilelinkfunctions/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the parameters `scope`, `element`, and `attrs` are defined for your custom directive, as per the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), but you can rename them to your like.

`scope`: this is the scope for your custom directive, similar to the `$scope` in a controller

`element`: this is the element of your custom directive

`attrs`: <s>this is the set of attributes in your custom directive</s>. (should be the attributes of the element, thanks to @zeroflagL for correction!)

For example, if you build a custom directive named `myDirective`, and you would probably use it in your html partials like this:

```
<my-directive num-rows="3"></my-directive>
```

Here, the `num-rows` is an attribute for your directive, and you can get its value in your `link` function:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log('num-rows:', attrs.numRows);
    //you can change its value, too
    attrs.$set('numRows', '10'); //attrs setter

    //you can watch for its changes to trigger some event
    attrs.$observe('numRows', function(newVal) {
       console.log('trigger some event for the changes in numRows here');
    });
}
```

Also, in the link function above, you can bind the element/directive to an action:

```
element.bind('click', function() {
   console.log('do something with the click event');
});
```

I suggest you spend some time reading the documentation. The link function can take a 4th parameter that is the controller of another directive that you require in your custom directive. e.g.:

```
require: '^ngModel'
....

function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: _"attrs: this is the set of attributes in your custom directive"_ should be "the attributes of the element".

Answer (score 0):

**scope**: this is the scope for your custom directive, similar to the `$scope` in a controller

**element**: this is the element of your custom directive

**attrs**: attrs nothing but a parameter